# sync/copy folders from source dir only if folders exist in target dir

Tags: bash, if-statement, copy

I'm trying to write a bash script in ubuntu to do a copy of some files.. I'm working on a small Android project, where i'm translating the apps each week. I'm VERY new to bash scripting, so please bear with me ;)

I want my script to check the target directory and see if my source directory contains the same folders. If it does, it should copy (and overwrite if needed) my source folders to the target dir, preserving the structure. But also adding whatever extra files and folders i might have within those source folders.

Let's say i have folder1, folder2, folder3 in my source dir, but only folder1 and folder2 in the target dir. Then i only need folder1 and folder2 from the source dir copied to the target dir.

The content of the target dir changes often, that's why i need the check before it copies the folders/files over.

Btw, the folders in both source and target dir are named like: folder1.apk - it has an extension so it looks like a file..

Hope i provided enough info ;)

EDIT:

I ended up doing this:

```
    for dir in `find * -maxdepth 0 -type d`; do
    cp -r -f /source/$dir /destination
    done
```

Don't know if it's the best way, but seems to do the job ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would probably take a look at [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) tool, which has lot of options and easy to use (no need to use own scripts). For example, one of the options that will be useful in your case:

```
--existing              skip creating new files on receiver
```

So, the following should do the job:

```
rsync -vur --existing ~/project/source /mnt/target/
```

And one of the possible benefits that you can sync files the same way through network if you will need to or even use it as a daemon to automatically sync files.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with this one is, that if i got matching directories in the source and target dir, i sometimes have extra/new files and folders in the source withing the main folder, which then doesn't get copied over. It's the main/top folder that determines wether or not the content should be copied over.

Comment: You can similarly `rsync src/* dst/`

Comment: @user1170663 I am sure that you can achieve the goal by playing with its options, for example --files-from=FILE option allows to specify the list of exact files you need to sync.